# Server returning incorrect file content when using Glassfish 3.1.2, JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces and ThemeRoller

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces, glassfish-3, themeroller

Im developing stylesheets to a web page which is using Glassfish 3.1.2, JSF 2.0, PrimeFaces and ThemeRoller.
The problem is that when the page is loaded, the content of the files included in header are wrong. 
For example fonts.css contains jQuery javascript library, Prime faces CSS contains my own css styling etc.
I tried to disable default Prime Faces CSS styling ( http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/remove-all-default-css-styling-from-primefaces/ ) but that didnt help at all.
What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

We resolved this situation to be caused by a NullPointerException from a library we used. The Exception was (is) well hiding in the log and didn't give actually any hint it could have this effect (and it's still unclear why the GF server behaves this way => GlassFish serving wrong files when some session operation got hit by NPE (JQuery js instead of css)). We have a workaround for it, but with some cost.